# How to partly merge repeated field into message?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have two messages of the same type `MyMSG`, that we will call `A` and `B`:

```
message MyMSG {
  repeated int msg_bucket = 1;
}
```

I want to copy one `msg_bucket` (*just one*, such as `A.msg_bucket(0)`) in `A` into `B`. not `MergeFrom` but partly merge.

Which function should I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Marc Gravell♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) pointed out, there is no automatism to do that.

**The most simple way** would be, to simply add a new `msg_bucket` to the container you want it to be "merged" into (`B`), then assigning the corresponding value, or copying in case you had a message instead of an int.

**Another way** would be, to serialize `B` into a container, creating a new `MyMSG C`, which does only contain the fields you want to merge, appending the serialisation of that new container to the serialized `B`, and finally parsing `B` from the serialized data.

```
MyMSG A, B, C; //considered initialized as described above
std::vector<char> serializedContainer(500);
B.SerializeToArray(serializedContainer.data(), serializedContainer.size());
C.SerializeToArray(serializedContainer.data() + B.ByteSize(), serializedContainer.size() - B.ByteSize());
B.ParseFromArray(serializedContainer.data(), B.ByteSize() + C.ByteSize());
```

Comment: Yes, at last, I use memcpy to merge partly.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you should create a separate `MyMSG` instance that has **just** the `msg_bucket` values that you want to serialize, and *serialize that instance*. No library that I know of has an API that allows you to indicate discreet items from an existing list to serialize ("index 0, 7 and 42 only, please").

Comment: I added one msg_bucket by int* one_msg = A.add_msg_bucket() and *int = B.msg_bucket(idx)

Comment: @edwardpku and... what happened?